# XML - XSLT List of elements - Joining elements with same attribute value

Tags: xml, for-loop, xslt

I'm trying to produce a XML file with a certain structure but I'm stuck,

This is my input XML file:

```
    <report>
    <page name="Simple MasterPage">
        <table id="__bookmark_1">
            <table-band band-type="BAND_HEADER">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <label>PERSONNAME</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>PERSONID</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>NUMELEM</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>CREATIONDATE</label>
                    </cell>
<cell>
                        <label>CREATIONDATE</label>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>John</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>John</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>John</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>3</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>John</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>4</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>John</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>5</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Marie</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>6</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Marie</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>p2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>7</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2018-06-21</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
        </table>
    </page>
</report>
```

This is the XSLT I'm using to transform it, that user @Parfait teached me how to build on a very similar post:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:template match="/report/page/table">
     <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.0">
            <!--Para comecar da 2 tabela-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="table-band[position() &gt; 1] "/>
     </entry> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="top_build-attrib">
      <xsl:param name="label_val"/>
      <xsl:param name="attrib_nm"/>
       <xsl:variable name="row_num" select="count(table-band[1]/row/cell[label=$label_val]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
       <xsl:attribute name="{$attrib_nm}"><xsl:value-of select="table-band[2]/row/cell[position()=$row_num]/data"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="build-attrib">
      <xsl:param name="label_val"/>
      <xsl:param name="attrib_nm"/>
       <xsl:variable name="row_num" select="count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label=$label_val]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
       <xsl:attribute name="{$attrib_nm}"><xsl:value-of select="row/cell[position()=$row_num]/data"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="elem_value">
      <xsl:param name="label_val"/>
       <xsl:variable name="row_num" select="count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label=$label_val]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="row/cell[position()=$row_num]/data"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table-band">

            <person>
                <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                   <xsl:with-param name="label_val">PERSONNAME</xsl:with-param>
                   <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">personName</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>

                <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                   <xsl:with-param name="label_val">PERSONID</xsl:with-param>
                   <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">personID</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>

                <listOfElements>
                    <element>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">NUMELEM</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">numElem</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">CREATIONDATE</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">creationDate</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                   </element>
                </listOfElements>
            </person> 
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this this the result I get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.0">
        <person personID="p1" personName="John">
         <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="1"/>
         </listOfElements>
        </person>
        <person personID="p1" personName="John">
          <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="2"/>
          </listOfElements>
        </person>
        <person personID="p1" personName="John">
          <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="3"/>
          </listOfElements>
        </person>
        <person personID="p1" personName="John">
          <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="4"/>
          </listOfElements>
        </person>
        <person personID="p1" personName="John">
          <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="5"/>
          </listOfElements>
        </person>
        <person personID="p2" personName="Marie">
          <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="6"/>
          </listOfElements>
        </person>
        <person personID="p2" personName="Marie">
          <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="7"/>
          </listOfElements>
        </person>
     </entry>
```

But the result I'm looking for and that am required to prodocue is this one:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <entry>
       <person personID="p1" personName="John">
        <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="1" />
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="2" />
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="3" />
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="4" />
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="5"/>
        </listOfElements>
       </person>
       <person personID="p2" personName="Marie">
        <listOfElements>
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="6" />
            <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="7" />
        </listOfElements>
       </person>
    </entry>
```

Meaning that the I'm not being able to produce the `listOfElements` like I should, I'm printing a new `person` node instead of "joining" the `element` nodes in the same `person` node (inside the `listOfElements` node)

I know that the solution must have something to do with comparing the `presonID` or `personName` attributes, but I'm just not getting there...

I really need some help guys, thank you!

**EDIT**

I tried addin the `xsl:for-each-group` before each `element` tag but I still get the same result. Did the following:

```
               <listOfElements>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="table-band[@band-type='BAND_DETAIL']/row" group-by="cell[2]/data">
                    <element>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">NUMELEM</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">numElem</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">CREATIONDATE</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">creationDate</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                   </element>
                   </xsl:for-each-group>
                </listOfElements>
```

**EDIT**
    I changed the input xml and output, meaning that the input xml lost the NUMDOC and CREATIONDATE elements, and gained a new one, ELEMENTTYPE,

So, I lost the grouping factor I used in the inner `for-each-group`, that was `NUMDOC`, like @Parfait teached me. Now I don't know how to group the elements with only having the `ELEMENTTYPE`. Note that I want to be able to have, for the same person, different elements with the same `ELEMENTTYPE`, so this can't be use for the factor in the `for-each-group`, or can it?

INPUT XML:(UPDATED)

```
    <report>
        <page name="Simple MasterPage">
            <table id="__bookmark_1">
                <table-band band-type="BAND_HEADER">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <label>PERSONNAME</label>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <label>PERSONID</label>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <label>ELEMENTTYPE</label>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>John</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p1</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>001</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>John</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p1</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>001</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>John</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p1</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>002</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>John</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p1</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>001</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>John</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p1</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>002</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>Marie</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p2</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>001</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
                <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                    <row>
                        <cell>
                            <data>Marie</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>p2</data>
                        </cell>
                        <cell>
                            <data>001</data>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                </table-band>
            </table>
        </page>
    </report>
```

So the output I wanna get is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <entry>
           <person personID="p1" personName="John">
            <listOfElements>
                <element elementType="001" />
                <element elementType="001" />
                <element elementType="002" />
                <element elementType="001" />
                <element elementType="002" />
            </listOfElements>
           </person>
           <person personID="p2" personName="Marie">
            <listOfElements>
                <element elementType="001" />
                <element elementType="001" />
            </listOfElements>
           </person>
        </entry>
```

I don't know what to use in the inner `for-each-group`, before , like @Parfait showed me, I used `NUMDOC`, but now I don't have anything to distinguish between docs!

Thanks!

Alexandre Jacinto

Comment: It is called "grouping" and if you really use XSLT 2 or 3 then you will for instance find examples of using `for-each-group` (e.g. `xsl:for-each-group select="table-band[@band-type='BAND_DETAIL']/row" group-by="cell[1]/data"`) in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples or in any XSLT 2 book or tutorial like http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/training/index.htm#ptux

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for you quick response! I'm gonna look into it and try and figure it out.

Comment: @MartinHonnen with this: ( xsl:for-each-group select="table-band[@band-type='BAND_DETAIL']/row" group-by="cell[1]/data" ) it would be grouped by personName right? Or would it be by personID?

Comment: The grouping would be by the `data` value of the first `cell` in each row which has names like `John`, if you want to group by another cell like the second cell use `group-by="cell[2]/data"`. I couldn't tell from your sample data which is the exact grouping key you want and the snippet was meant as a hint for you to try.

Comment: @MartinHonnen you're right, I wasn't clear about the grouping key. I have to change my Java code to use Saxon and support XSLT 2.0. Thank you!

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried what you said after using Saxon but I get the same result. I edited my question so you can see what I did

Comment: Why did you delete your earlier question especially since you build off it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879738/xml-transform-xslt/50890232#50890232) and even reference it here? My answer was deleted. StackOverflow works for current and future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applyling a two-layered `<xsl:for-each-group>` in your last template of current XSLT, pointing to the *PERSONNAME* and *NUMELEM* corresponding position in first `<table-band>`:

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBt9/1)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/report/page">
      <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.0">
        <!--Para comecar da 2 tabela-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>
      </entry> 
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="top_build-attrib">
     <xsl:param name="label_val"/>
     <xsl:param name="attrib_nm"/>
      <xsl:variable name="row_num" select="count(table-band[1]/row/cell[label=$label_val]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="{$attrib_nm}"><xsl:value-of select="table-band[2]/row/cell[position()=$row_num]/data"/></xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="build-attrib">
     <xsl:param name="label_val"/>
     <xsl:param name="attrib_nm"/>
      <xsl:variable name="row_num" select="count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label=$label_val]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="{$attrib_nm}"><xsl:value-of select="row/cell[position()=$row_num]/data"/></xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="elem_value">
     <xsl:param name="label_val"/>
      <xsl:variable name="row_num" select="count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label=$label_val]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="row/cell[position()=$row_num]/data"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="table">

       <xsl:for-each-group select="table-band" group-by="row/cell[position()=
                      count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label='PERSONNAME']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/data">
         <person>
            <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
               <xsl:with-param name="label_val">PERSONID</xsl:with-param>
               <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">personID</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
               <xsl:with-param name="label_val">PERSONNAME</xsl:with-param>
               <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">personName</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <listOfElements>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="row/cell[position()=
                      count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label='NUMELEM']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]">
                    <element>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">NUMELEM</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">numElem</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">CREATIONDATE</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">creationDate</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                   </element>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </listOfElements>
        </person> 

       </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi again! Do you know how to, when using Saxon, avoid attributes always being printed on a new line? In the .NET XSLT Fiddle, when I use MS processor it prints the attributes (from the same element) all in one line, but when I use Saxon it prints each in a new line.

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014574/xslt-xml-for-each-group-with-xslchoose , it is an extension to this one, and my solution is an extension to your solution here, do you think you might know what the problem is? @Parfait

Comment: I edited my expected output to something a bit difficult... If I wanted to group elements also of the same person, but what if the only attribute that the element had was something like elementType, meaning that different elements of the same person would have the same value in this attribute, how would I distinguish them? Thank you! @Parfait

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal stylesheet incorporating my suggestion made in a comment (with the grouping key adjusted to take the data value from the second cell):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/report/page/table">
   <entry versao="1.0">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="table-band[@band-type='BAND_DETAIL']/row" group-by="cell[2]/data">
            <person personID="{current-grouping-key()}" personName="{cell[1]/data}">
                <listOfElements>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </listOfElements>
            </person> 
       </xsl:for-each-group>
    </entry> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <element creationDate="{cell[4]/data}" numElem="{cell[3]/data}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtq7 where Saxon 9.8 HE is used the result for your sample is

```
<entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.0">
   <person personID="p1" personName="John">
      <listOfElements>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="1"/>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="2"/>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="3"/>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="4"/>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="5"/>
      </listOfElements>
   </person>
   <person personID="p2" personName="Marie">
      <listOfElements>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="6"/>
         <element creationDate="2018-06-21" numElem="7"/>
      </listOfElements>
   </person>
</entry>
```

Comment: This works if *PERSONNAME*, *PERSONID*, *NUMELEM*, *CREATIONDATE* retains their same order. Here you hard-code the node indexes. Hence the use of the `call-templates`.

Comment: @Parfait, I simply tried to spell out the grouping suggestion I made earlier in a comment and that the poster said he couldn't get to work, then also tried to populate some of the data based on the input cell values. The suggestion was made based on presented input and output, I didn't try to understand and reimplement anything else the presented code might try to achieve. With the `numElem` I expected to get some wrong result but at least for the sample it looked fine. Not sure what the original problem was without the grouping.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you so much for you help, I really wasn't getting there! Thank you

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen! I'm gonna ask you the same I asked @Parfait, do you know how to, when using Saxon, avoid attributes always being printed on a new line? In the .NET XSLT Fiddle, when I use MS processor it prints the attributes (from the same element) all in one line, but when I use Saxon it prints each in a new line.

Comment: You can ask new questions as separate questions with the right tags (e.g. [tag:saxon]), but make sure you check the relevant documentation first http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html

Comment: But what's really odd it's that in your example in the XSLT fiddle link you posted and also in Parfait's, where both of you are using Saxon, the attributes come in the same line...

Comment: It depends on the line length whether Saxon tries to break up attributes into separate lines, that feature is settable (`saxon:line-length`) in the commercial versions of Saxon.

Comment: Do you know how do I set it so it doesn´t break it into separate lines?

Comment: Well, the documentation says about `saxon:line-length` "attributes are output on a new line if they would otherwise extend beyond this column position" so you will have to set it to a very high value you know your lines are not going to exceed e.g. `<xsl:output saxon:line-length="10000" .../>`. But as I said, Saxon extension are usually only available in the commercial PE and/or EE editions, not in the open-source HE.

Comment: Ok ok thank you, attributes being printed in a new line isn't gonna be a problem I think...

Comment: @MartinHonnen I posted a new question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014574/xslt-xml-for-each-group-with-xslchoose , it is an extension to this one, I don't know why it's not working like it's supposed to

Comment: I edited my expected output to something a bit difficult... If I wanted to group elements also of the same person, but what if the only attribute that the element had was something like elementType, meaning that different elements of the same person would have the same value in this attribute, how would I distinguish them? Thank you! @MartinHonnen