# XSLT - XML - For-each-group with xsl:choose

Tags: xml, for-loop, if-statement, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
<report>
    <page name="Simple MasterPage">
        <table id="__bookmark_1">
            <table-band band-type="BAND_HEADER">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <label>OPTYPE</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>REPORTNUM</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>REPORTNAME</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>CREATIONDATE</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>PERSONNAME</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>PERSONID</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>NUMELEM</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>NATIONALITY</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>IDTYPE</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>STREET</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>CITY</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>POSTCODE</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>BIRTHDATE</label>
                    </cell>
                     <cell>
                        <label>GENDER</label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <label>ALTPERSONID</label>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>A</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>firstReport</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2017-01-31</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Alex Jones</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>100001</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Portugal</data>
                    </cell>
                     <cell>
                        <data>Portuguese</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>i1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Jones Street</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Lisbon</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2600</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1997-02-04</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>M</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data></data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
             <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>B</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>firstReport</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2017-01-31</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Ana Maria</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>100002</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Portugal</data>
                    </cell>
                     <cell>
                        <data>Portuguese</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>i2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Maria Street</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Lisbon</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2600</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1997-02-06</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>F</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>alt1</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>B</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>firstReport</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2017-01-31</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Ana Maria</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>100002</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>3</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Portugal</data>
                    </cell>
                     <cell>
                        <data>Portuguese</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>i2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Maria Street</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Lisbon</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2600</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1997-02-06</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>F</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>alt1</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>B</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>firstReport</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2017-01-31</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Ana Maria</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>100002</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>4</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Portugal</data>
                    </cell>
                     <cell>
                        <data>Portuguese</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>i2</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Maria Street</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Lisbon</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2600</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1997-02-06</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>F</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>alt1</data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
            <table-band band-type="BAND_DETAIL">
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        <data>A</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>firstReport</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2017-01-31</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Alex Jones</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>100002</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>5</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Portugal</data>
                    </cell>
                     <cell>
                        <data>Portuguese</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>i1</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Jones Street</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>Lisbon</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>2600</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>1997-02-04</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data>M</data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
                        <data></data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </table-band>
        </table>
    </page>
</report>
```

This is part of the XSLT I'm using to transform it, that user @Parfait teached me how to build on a very similar post. If OPTYPE is B, then the output will have another output element called altPersonID; Then idType will set the personInfo attributes.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


....

    <xsl:for-each-group select="table-band" group-by="row/cell[position()=
                      count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label='PERSONNAME']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/data">

    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$op_type = 'A'">

        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$id_type = 'i1'"> 

        ....

        <!--HERE IM USING FOR EACH GROUP-->

            <listOfElements>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="row/cell[position()=
                      count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label='NUMELEM']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]">
                    <element>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">CREATIONDATE</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">creationDate</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="build-attrib">
                            <xsl:with-param name="label_val">NUMELEM</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="attrib_nm">numElem</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                   </element>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </listOfElements>
        ....

      </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

basically it's outputing always in the same way, whether is OPTYPE is B or A and IDTYPE is i1 or i2

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to give a precise answer because you have not shown your expected output, but it looks like the problem is that you have declared the `op_type` and `id_type` variables before the `xsl:for-each-group`

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:variable name="op_type">
    <xsl:value-of select="table-band/row/cell[position()=1]/data"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="id_type">
    <xsl:value-of select="table-band/row/cell[position()=10]/data"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="table-band" group-by="row/cell[position()=
                  count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label='PERSONNAME']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/data">
    <xsl:choose>
       ....
```

What this means is that (as you are using XSLT 3.0), that `op_type` variable will contain the value of all "optype" cells concatenated into one string. You could see this if you did an `xsl:value-of` after your declaration

```
<xsl:value-of select="$op_type" />
```

This returns the following

```
EI EU EU EU EI
```

What you need to do move the declaration inside the `xsl:for-each-group` so that it is selects the value for the first row in the group.

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="table-band" group-by="row/cell[position()=
                      count(ancestor::table/table-band[1]/row/cell[label='PERSONNAME']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/data">
    <xsl:variable name="op_type" select="row/cell[position()=1]/data"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id_type" select="row/cell[position()=10]/data" />
    <xsl:choose>
       ...
```

Comment: I edited my question to have the expected output @Tim C (image link). Thank you for you answer!

Comment: I did what you suggested and in fact I verified that when the declaration of the variables is before the 'for-each-group' the <xsl:value-of select="$op_type" /> returns "EI EU EU EU EI", but when I moved the declaration inside the 'for-each-group' it seems to not be returning anything..., so I guess it's not matching anything?

Comment: Nevermind! I just noticed that in you suggestion you took the 'table-band' out of the path... Just did that and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: It worked when using the .NET XSLT Fiddle, but when I try and run it in my Java program (using Saxon HE 9.8), it doesn't group the elements of the same person...

Comment: I am not sure why, as .Net XSLT Fiddle also uses Saxon HE 9.8 by default.

Comment: I was using it wrong... Thanks! Can you help me with this question though? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991149/xml-xslt-list-of-elements-joining-elements-with-same-attribute-value , see latest EDIT

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest doing this kind of thing as a two-phase transformation. First transform the input XML to something more in the spirit of XML:

```
<reports>
 <report>
  <OPTYPE>EI</OPTYPE>
  <REPORT_NUM>1</REPORT_NUM>
  <REPORT_NAME>...</REPORT_NAME> 
  <CREATION_DATE>2017-01-31</CREATION_DATE>
  ...
 </report>
 <report>
  ...
 </report>
</reports>
```

and then do the specific transformation involving grouping etc.

This pipeline approach leads to code that is simpler and more reusable. You will find that the first phase can be used regardless what processing you are doing in the second phase, so all your manipulations of this XML document type will become simpler.

I haven't tried to understand the processing you are actually doing, but I can see that the logic is greatly complicated by the inconvenient format of the input, and I'm sure it would all become a lot easier if you sorted that out first.

There are many ways of organising a pipeline of transformations in XSLT. You can do it within a single stylesheet, by capturing the result of the first phase in a variable, and then using that variable as input to the second phase; or you can use multiple stylesheets connected together using a variety of technologies including XProc, Java programs, Ant scripts, shell scripts, or any number of XSLT-based application frameworks.

Comment: Yes, what complicates everything is the input XML... I edited my question to have the expected output (image link)